# Efficient way to replace ~/ with application path?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, string, optimization

I have HTML content coming from a database that gets rendered to a web page (like a CMS). In the HTML content, I want to allow ~/ in the paths of images and links to let the system ResolveUrl's. So what is an efficient method to do this? I will be using this C# across web forms and MVC. Thanks for any help o advice.

Comment: Are you looking for an alternative to `ResolveUrl`? What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option might be to use the [Html Agiltiy Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the HTML and extract the URLs, then resolve them and update the HTML with the resolved URLs.